# Yii findAllByAttributes between two dates from a single table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I need a support from you guys.
I have a table which keep the count of  people visited my blog.
**Sql Query**

```
Select * from count where (visitdate between '2015-09-01' AND '2015-10-30')
```

I want to convert this query to  **yii findAllByAttributes**.
I have tried the following method which shows ony one count.But in my table they shows me 15.

```
$date_start = '2015-09-01';
$date_start = '2015-10-15';
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;        
$criteria->addBetweenCondition("visitdate",$date_start,$date_end,'AND');
$model = Viewcount::model()-> findAllByAttributes($criteria);
$countreport = count($model);
echo $countreport;
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can try with this

```
$date_start = '2015-09-01';
$date_start = '2015-10-15';
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;        
$criteria->addBetweenCondition("visitdate",$date_start,$date_end,'AND');
$model = Viewcount::model()-> findAll($criteria);
$countreport = count($model);
echo $countreport;
```